# Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Host

Tags: powershell, clr

I'm attempting to invoke Windows Powershell cmdlets via Visual Studio .NET. However, I'm getting the exception shown below when I try to call a function.The **Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll** wasn't initially in that path so I copied it over from another location. Is this the right way of installing a snap-in? It still spits out that exception and I'm not sure why. Any nudges in the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks.

System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException: Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Host because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly '**file:///C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll**' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException:
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadMshSnapinAssembly(PSSnapInInfo mshsnapinInfo)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadPSSnapIn(PSSnapInInfo mshsnapinInfo)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadPSSnapIns(Collection`1 mshsnapinInfos, PSConsoleLoadException& warning)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.CreateDefaultConfiguration()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfiguration.Create()

Comment: I afraid it is not quite clear what you do. Could you please at least provide a block of code that actually causes that exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) tool provided by MS. It helps in such problems, when some assemblies can not be loaded.