# Package manager console fails to initialize

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to open package manager console in Visual studio 2013 update 3 I get this error :

> Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Management because of the following error: > Could not load file or assembly 
>   'file:///C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll' or 
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have uninstalled/Re installed powershell. It didn't change anything.
any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849410/cannot-load-windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-powershell-host